# Can not sort by key in mongodb based on an meteor app

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am learning to build a meteor app following an book.

The step is to sort a post collection by votes. https://github.com/DiscoverMeteor/Microscope/commit/chapter13-5

```
posts: function() {
 return Posts.find({}, this.findOptions());
}
findOptions: function() {
 return {sort: this.sort, limit: this.postsLimit()};
```

But the UI sort did not work.
So I tried to type in the shell mongodb on my localhost server.

>  db.posts.find({}, {sort: {votes: -1, submitted: -1, _id: -1}} )

and it failed with msg:

> error: { "$err" : "Unsupported projection option: votes", "code" : 13097 }

Could someone give me an hint? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB uses a slightly different sintax for for sort and limit: insted of different objects, it uses different methods, like .sort() and .limit(). More info [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/.../method/db.collection.find/).